Giving a counter example to describe what the invention is not
Are there any pros and cons of giving a counter example that describes what the feature or embodiment is not?

I'm not sure this is on topic for this site; it doesn't seem like the question is fundamentally related to patents. If there were a technical writing SE site it might be appropriate there. The specification must describe how to make and use the invention clearly and (reasonably) concisely. I can imagine that sometimes a negative example is helpful to guide the reader, as in: "Note that the cross-coupling described does not equate to a Schmitt trigger because ...". If you have a question about a negative limitation in a claim that might be more on-topic.

For clarification it can be helpful. “Although structure 101 as shown in figure 1 could be mistaken for an ABC, note that it is an XYZ,”
Also, as pointed out in a comment, it might be important to support a negative limitation.
But dangerous if it can lead to limitations unnecessarily being read into claims.
